# Mysql gives always syntax error even for simple queries

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I connect with the terminal to a database locally and when I try to execute simple queries to a table I get back a syntax error message.
I have a table named user, I run
  `select * from user;`
and then I get back

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the >manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right >syntax to use near ''user'' at line 1`

I tried to run the same select query with capitals too but nothing happens

I have integrated the database with my API using hibernate and the app throws a similar exception

I did not change any code or something in the database. The previous week I ran it works properly. Also, I do not have custom queries in hibernate, only repository methods that communicate with the DB.

Thanks!

Comment: user is a reserved SQL keyword. Choose another name for your table of column.

Comment: user is not a reserved SQL keyword. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html where `USER` appears, but not with the "(R)" note that indictates it's a _reserved_ keyword. I just tested creating a table called user, and it works fine.

Comment: If you still think user is a reserved keyword, you can put it in back-ticks like any other reserved keyword you use as an identifier: `select * from \`user\``. But I am guessing that won't fix the error, because the cause is something else. I don't think robocode has shown the real SQL query they are running.

Comment: @JBNizet, this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370321/postgresql-syntax-error-at-or-near-user, that's a question about PostgreSQL. The error reported in this question is clearly one from MySQL. I have voted to reopen this question.

Comment: Oh come on. They both use SQL. And user is a keyword in both. And the fix is the same for both: don't use keywords as table or column name. There's no (R), OK. So it's a keyword and not a reserved keyword. Big deal.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I am not sure about that user is reversed by default since it was working but make sense to be reversed. I renamed the table from user  to users and finally i can query it.

Comment: @JBNizet, `USER` is a [reserved keyword in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html), but it's a non-reserved keyword in MySQL. You can't make that something else be true by saying "oh come on."

Comment: It's listed, under the title "keywords and reserved words in MySQL", in the page of the official MySQL documentation that you linked yourself. What more do you need to accept that it's a MySQL keyword?

Comment: It is in fact a keyword, but not a _reserved_ keyword. The difference is whether you can use the keyword as an identifier without delimiting it. As I posted in a comment above, I tested creating a table called `user` in MySQL, and that works without error.

Comment: And yet renaming the table from 'user' to 'users' turns a failing query into a working query.

Comment: In addition i want to note that i had another table that i could not query and this table contained the id of user table as foreign key. Finally i deleted the DB and constructed it again in order to solve all the problems i experienced.